# yshift in \foreach does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
        \foreach \line in {1,2,...,40} {
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-5mm]
                \foreach \letter/\position in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5} { 
                    \node at (0,0) {\normalsize{\line}};
                    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.2mm] at ({\position * 0.5},0) {\letter};
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output does not spread out 5 mm as intended. I am not sure where should I put `yshift` in the code.

[Original code from Github](https://gist.github.com/kazyka/7a69e540b17690286505522355e8819c)

Comment: You shift always the same -5mm. That number is absolute, not relative. You should use something like `-5mm*\line` or similar...

Comment: @Rmamo Thank you very much!